# ios app got rejected for section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, xcode10

My ios app is available in app store. But it's update has been got rejected for section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.

[app store link of the app](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1098124546?ls=1&mt=8)

There are three (weekly, monthly, yearly) auto renew subscriptions for my app. Now i am using only one (monthly) subscription in my app. But in app store it shows free trial for three days and to subscribe to my weekly subscription not the monthly subscription. When anyone click on free trial, then if app is installed, user is taken to the app but nothing happen, or if app is not installed, then first app started to install and after finishing user is taken to the app and nothing happen.

Now I think the solution is when anyone enter the app by clicking with free trial from app store, the app should show the weekly subscription detail and purchase dialogue box. But how can i detect this event and can show purchase subscription dialogue box?

[Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5pcW.jpg)

Message From Apple:

> We noticed that your app or its metadata did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.
>
> When the user initiates an in-app purchase on the App Store, they are
>   taken into your app to continue the transaction. However, the
>   following information must be displayed to the user prior to the
>   purchase:
>
> ￼– Information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription,
>   including • Title of publication or service • Length of subscription
>   (time period and content or services provided during each subscription
>   period) • Price of subscription, and price per unit if appropriate •
>   Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
>   • Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at
>   least 24-hours before the end of the current period • Account will be
>   charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current
>   period, and identify the cost of the renewal • Subscriptions may be
>   managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the
>   user's Account Settings after purchase • Any unused portion of a free
>   trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a
>   subscription to that publication, where applicable ￼– A link to the
>   terms of use ￼– A link to the privacy policy
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app to include the missing
>   information prior to initiating any auto-renewing subscription
>   purchases within your app. Adding the above information to the
>   StoreKit modal alert is not sufficient; the information must also be
>   displayed within the app itself, and it must be displayed clearly and
>   conspicuously during the purchase flow without requiring additional
>   action from the user, such as opening a link.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was tricky but I solved it.

Apple gives you the conditions you need to display, in point form. I had to create a privacy policy and terms of use (these conditions) and post them on the app’s website. I put those conditions, including links to the website, in a full screen VC and asked the user to accept them before purchase. I also put them in the app description on the app store. It was accepted.

Be aware that Apple recently specified requirements for the privacy policy and terms of use. I’m sure I have to change my privacy policy if I want to update the app.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Thank you. But can u tell me how can i detect app is launched from app store by clicking the free trial button.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "app is launched from the app store". The app is always launched from a device, and you control what happens through the code. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: if app is launched from another app. 
In app store there is a button below our app "free trial". If user press this button user is taken to our app. 
How can i detect this event.

Comment: @SarwarJahan did you ever find the answer to this question? Going through this right now...

Answer (score 0):

The final solution that works for me is that i was showing only monthly subscription in my app though in app store user was shown that this app has weekly subscription. So i added weekly subscription in my app and apple accepted this.